# Why $|<Tz,z>| \le\sup\limits_{\|u\|\le 1} |<Tu,u>| \|z\|^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

I'm having trouble understanding a technical argument of a proof similar to Theorem C.51,p 4 from [this link](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section5a_adjoint.pdf), where the statement to prove is: $\|T\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\le 1}|<Tx,x>|$ for a bounded linear self-adjoint operator on a hilbert space $T\in L(H)$.

In a sketch it is defined that $M:=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\le 1}|<Tx,x>|$ and it shall be proved that $\|T\| \le M$. The line I don't understand is:
$$4 Re(<Tx,x>)\le |<T(x+y),x+y>|+|<T(x-y),x-y>|\le M\|x+y\|^2+M\|x-y\|^2=M(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)$$

My question boils down to the second estimate where it should hold that $|<Tz,z>|\le \sup\limits_{\|u\|\le1 }|<Tu,u>|\|z\|^2 = M\|z\|^2$ for $z\in H$, $\|z\|\le 1$ ( or even for any $z\in H$?).

I tought about using the estimate $|<Tz,z>|\le \|Tz\|\|z\|\le \|T\|\|z\|^2$ but since $\|T\|\le M$ is what should be proved I can't use it.
So I'm stuck here and don't see how to prove the estimate in question?

Comment: Note that, for every $x\ne0$, $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\|x\|^2\cdot\langle Tu,u\rangle$ for some $\|u\|=1$, namely, $u=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$.

Comment: Can you provide more details/references on $<Tx,x>=\|x\|^2$ cause i have never seen this statement before.

Comment: Did I state that $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\|x\|^2$? Where?

Comment: seems its not my day today :P - My fault. - I've got it now. Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

We need to show:
$$
|\langle Tz,z\rangle| \le \|z\|^2\sup\limits_{\|u\|\le 1} |\langle Tu,u\rangle| 
$$

Clearly, it holds for $z=0$. If $z\ne 0$, and $w=\dfrac{z}{\|z\|}$, then $\|w\|=1$, and
$$
|\langle Tz,z\rangle|=|\langle T(\|z\|w),\|z\|w\rangle|=\|z\|^2|\langle Tw,w\rangle|
\le \|z\|^2\sup_{\|w\|=1}|\langle Tw,w\rangle|.
$$